# Err.Number vs try-catch in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, exception, try-catch

I have inherited an old VB.net-project. The code mostly uses try-catch for error-handling. However in some places I have found `If Err.Number <> 0 Then`.

If an error occurs, what decides if an `Exception` should be thrown, or just setting `Err`?

I don't want to handle error both ways...

Comment: The infamous On Error Resume Next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Err`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka13cy19%28VS.90%29.aspx) object is use with the old-style `On Error` error handling construct, that is a remainder from classic VB. `Try-Catch` is the more current .NET style of error handling.

You can learn more about this, and the difference in [Error Handling in Visual Basic.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973849.aspx).

Comment: How do I decide which error handling is active?
Just On Error Goto 0 should set old-style, I think.

Comment: @leiflundgren: whatever construct is closest to the code you are looking at will be the active one. You can mix both styles, but not within a method. So you can have one method setting up error handling with an `On Error` statement, and then call another method that uses `Try-Catch`.

Comment: @fredrik-mork: Ah So if I write On Error Goto 0 (or similar) in a method, I use that stile. Otherwise it's try-catch?

Comment: @leiflundgren: yes, almost correct. In order to use `Try-Catch` you will of course need to include such statements in your code. If you have neither `On Error` nor `Try-Catch`, any exceptions will be unhandled and crash your app instead.

Comment: @fredrik-mork: Ah. The fault was assuming existing code was correct. ;) Added try-catch as I am used to now. Thanks!

Comment: @leiflundgren: you are welcome :-) And yes, `On Error` should be considered as legacy. `Try-Catch` is the way to go for any new code.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the old code was using On Error Resume Next. Make sure you understand what it does, its kind of odd!

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) explain it

> On Error Resume Next causes execution to continue with the statement immediately following the statement that caused the run-time error, or with the statement immediately following the most recent call out of the procedure containing the On Error Resume Next statement. This statement allows execution to continue despite a run-time error. You can place the error-handling routine where the error would occur rather than transferring control to another location within the procedure.

You would then use If Err.Number <> 0 to check whether an error had occurred.